# How to pass a class as a model attribute?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a class Order, that i pass with model.addAttribute to an html page. I want to display attribute order.customer.address and order.orderDetails.product.name , order.orderDetails.quanitity. But I get an error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWiIb.png).

```
@GetMapping("/orders")
    public String orders(Model model, Principal principal){
        if(principal == null){
            return "redirect:/login";
        }
        List<Order> orders = orderService.getAllOrders();
        model.addAttribute("orders", orders);
}
```

```
public class Order {
   
    private Long id;
...
    private String orderStatus;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", referencedColumnName = "customer_id")
    private Customer customer;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "order")  
    private List<OrderDetail> orderDetailList;
}
```

```
public class OrderDetail {
    private Long id;
    private int quantity;
    private double totalPrice;
    private double unitPrice;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", referencedColumnName = "order_id")
    private Order order;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", referencedColumnName = "product_id")
    private Product product;
}
```

```
<table class="table table-bordered" th:if="${size > 0}">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Order Index</th>
                            <th scope="col">Order Date</th>
                            <th scope="col">Order Items</th>
                            <th scope="col">Delivery address</th>
                            <th scope="col">Order Status</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr th:each="order : ${orders}">
                            <th scope="row" th:text="${order.id}"></th>
                            <td th:text="${order.orderDate}"></td>
                            <td th:text="${order.orderDetailList}"></td>
                            <td th:text="${order.customer.address}"></td>
                            <td th:text="${order.orderStatus}"></td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Comment: <th scope="row" th:text="${order.id}"></th>

<td th:text="${order.orderDate}"></td>

<td th:text="${order.orderStatus}"></td>
are displayed correctly if i comment out order.orderDetailList and order.customer.address

Comment: Order and OrderDetail are referencing each other. While that's valid scenario in java, it causes stackoverflow errors in serialization. The solution is to not send entities in the model, but to use [DTOs](https://www.baeldung.com/java-dto-pattern) for this purpose.

Comment: could you please tell what attribute i would need for storing products and their quantities (like smartphone - 2 pc, headphone - 1pc) in my OrderDto? Or do i need separate Dto for OrderDetails?

Comment: Yes, separate dto for details.